# vega-lite change rank order with a parameter not working for some reason

Tags: vega-lite

I have a  ranked chart that I want to change sort order for and it does not work for me; wonder if anyone can tell me what I missed.

I looked at it more, after posting the question and sort does not work at all, even without the signal from the dropdown.

[my chart](https://%5BOpen%20the%20Chart%20in%20the%20Vega%20Editor%5D(https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQUOQDMaZNKCQNMbCDQBecLcrmYkNWRDQgcSACYOrmpQCc4B42kxuGcJUwATxwTdHsHEABfKKUHJAtTWSQEMJB4xKViJEF-G1QAbW0yOFlMWwAhJDdypSRiMgB9aDYPWwBmSgAGHt6+-q7FZRzBRpUGMrQxJUEkJjhBWwBBawB3ODcAAgAVGlSh5AAPZpU21Gm7DahSixLbLsoANgGXgaGWj0b6jaQ79AAmSjtYEg0Fg9rvU5wMY5KD3SgARghSg+0Icnjh6GcqlUm1UbjYCE29VcIFRjVCbmuZV+aQeABZHkzmSzWc8etEFMUbrYALJzBZDEknVppTqvV5DKAjMZsCblc4zAWLdArCDrLa7fZKI4is4XSnU250p4Ss2Q0VfUhuWm2QHgh0gi2faWCTEgB5I51ojG2bG4-GE4kNb0Uq43W3oBlsmPM3qc7mTdC8tgmOoNPVpBHdM0SqUy8ZJi6zeYqkAAOT4mBopE2AHVWg4bDqkMdUWgEV0lIaI38PYjc5KUVCrT8+-TKP9B-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-TyWq2z7Q8-pm50c48L1Zx7z5SGavbHS+vhaokBQfB0wvsOBVQDH1UUYABTiuXTrDhJbEnABSZ6Lat3qL2EMgjZAI7VFqb3XZhprbHoEKHM2TXbx9tJV6fmLc4dUg7WFDm4cO8No4tzjhHdu5RO5p2SBnXuEd+7IxuLvKyJE1aI2prYH+U8a6zxqvPRuS8XDW2hnbK+KgFp0HYEbSGngaIZAYAgAoAByZmoosFGlpMPKAnDqqbAADybBStkXIaQPCRDqlI-wtge6lEDnANephN4gB4R4PhclBFDHAcgGip9Vr43QETEmB1yZCxdm7N+8NNHkjXHCVm2MsQNSai1eQC9NHaLgLo6yatD7GP+GfVxMsyCcxLn-XmliyaC1IRfAaN874Pyfv7CACwrBpAQDQJw2M4hAP+PSIJZQ6xwDejRJg0NnbPzsTXL6n1TG+29mo8oICbRgLDmgpuMdYGFHgSARB3dM5fR6bnWwfiAnGn0bgsu2UXS6SUNPcuss7hkNANA1ucCHJDKUF3ZBPdpbjLzlMveWtS74PQERc5t4Vm1zgnPWqyd7A2gQPkSOTArCLVAFYHAuhbCZKOlAJ+1cvEfNomwbAhIhjbGng3EAyR9jXNaGjGAadrjnjUTgNwgLUWo3RdNOAABeUlnCKhQr0AgThmwAD8mxOG52pODThqBOHONKCyoYSK0gyBqOtUSK1hbhIwWUTYmw-GY06SHbp8NVjfLYKsHp9zOlWzqHnVVNUUSop6ZowhyzBW4qvgYW+T0UX8sNc9BuG8aAwyBukBI7DKCqrEcSzYnYtUgHlQ4egaATxRCAA))

```
        {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {
    "autosize": {"contains": "padding", "resize": true, "type": "pad"}
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.32",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.20000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "-0.27",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "agent",
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AgentCalls", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "AvgAgtScore", "title": "avg score", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "percentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]}
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AvgAgtScore", "field": "avg_score", "op": "average"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentCalls", "field": "call_count", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "AgentPercentage", "format": ".2%"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "tooltip": "the agent percentage",
        "type": "text",
        "x": 5
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentPercentage", "field": "percentage", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "ScorePercentageCalc",
          "format": ".2%",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "score_desc", "title": "description"},
          {
            "field": "ScorePercentage",
            "format": ".2%",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "test",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentageCalc",
              "field": "score_calc",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentage",
              "field": "score_percentage",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["Bottom", "Top"]},
      "name": "sortChoice"
    },
    {
      "expr": "sortChoice==='Bottom' ? 'ascending':'descending'",
      "name": "sortOrder"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Agent  Scores",
   "transform": [
      {
        "window": [{
          "op": "rank",
          "as": "rank"
        }],
        "sort": [{ "field": "percentage", "order": {"signal": "sortOrder"}}]
      }, {
        "filter": "datum.rank <= 10" 
        
      }
    ],
  "width": 200
}
```

Comment: What is your desired goal? You're doing a rank as the first transform, not referencing that rank anywhere else and then aggregating the data multiple times losing any sort you would have had anyway. Can you clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to clean up your spec as much as possible.

Sort by y:

[image]

Sort by -y:

[image]

I've removed all your transforms and replaced with just a single one as that is all you need.

Spec:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {
    "autosize": {"contains": "padding", "resize": true, "type": "pad"}
  },
  "params": [
    {
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["Bottom", "Top"]},
      "name": "sortChoice"
    },
    {
      "expr": "sortChoice==='Bottom' ? 'ascending':'descending'",
      "name": "sortOrder"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Agent  Scores",
  "width": 200,
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.32",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.20000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "-0.27",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {
      "aggregate": [
        {"op": "average", "field": "percentage", "as": "AgentPercentage"},
        {"op": "average", "field": "score_calc", "as": "ScorePercentageCalc"}
      ],
      "groupby": ["agent"]
    }
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "agent",
      "type": "nominal", "sort":"-y"
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AgentCalls", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "AvgAgtScore", "title": "avg score", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "AgentPercentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]}
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"}
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "AgentPercentage", "format": ".2%"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "tooltip": "the agent percentage",
        "type": "text",
        "x": 5
      }
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "ScorePercentageCalc",
          "format": ".2%",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "score_desc", "title": "description"},
          {
            "field": "ScorePercentage",
            "format": ".2%",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "test",
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: wow thats nice!   I have so much to learn!!!

Comment: Don't forget to mark as solved and/or upvote if you found it helpful.

Comment: I have lots of advanced visuals here that might help your learning journey: https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I figured this out; I needed to be sorting 'Agents' and I wanted to limit the data by the top ten or bottom ten; there might be fifty agents in the data. The point about not referencing the rank is valid. [I think i removed it as a troubleshooting step and forgot...]

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "config": {
    "autosize": {"contains": "padding", "resize": true, "type": "pad"}
  },
  "data": {
    "name": "data",
    "values": [
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "3.0000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.60000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "0.13",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.10000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "-0.32",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Moe",
        "avg_score": "1.00000000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Answer Time",
        "max_score": 5,
        "percentage": "0.20000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "2.3333333333333333",
        "score_calc": "-0.27",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.46666666666666666000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Bart",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      },
      {
        "agent": "Mabel",
        "avg_score": "5.8000000000000000",
        "call_count": 5,
        "label": "Negative Words",
        "max_score": 10,
        "percentage": "0.58000000000000000000",
        "score_average": "4.2000000000000000",
        "score_calc": "0.16",
        "score_desc": "diff from avg",
        "score_percentage": "0.42000000000000000000"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "",
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "axis": {
        "labels": true,
        "tickBand": "center",
        "tickOpacity": 0,
        "title": ""
      },
      "field": "agent",
      "sort": {
        "field": "percentage",
        "op": "max",
        "order": {"signal": "sortOrder"}
      },
      "type": "nominal"
    }
  },
  "height": {"step": 16},
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "AgentCalls", "title": "calls", "type": "quantitative"},
          {"field": "AvgAgtScore", "title": "avg score", "type": "quantitative"}
        ],
        "x": {
          "aggregate": "average",
          "axis": null,
          "field": "percentage",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]}
        }
      },
      "mark": {"color": "#ddd", "tooltip": true, "type": "bar"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AvgAgtScore", "field": "avg_score", "op": "average"}
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentCalls", "field": "call_count", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"text": {"field": "AgentPercentage", "format": ".2%"}},
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "tooltip": "the agent percentage",
        "type": "text",
        "x": 5
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {"as": "AgentPercentage", "field": "percentage", "op": "average"}
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "condition": {
            "test": "datum['ScorePercentageCalc'] < 0",
            "value": "red"
          },
          "value": "green"
        },
        "text": {
          "field": "ScorePercentageCalc",
          "format": ".2%",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {"field": "score_desc", "title": "description"},
          {
            "field": "ScorePercentage",
            "format": ".2%",
            "title": "avg score",
            "type": "quantitative"
          }
        ]
      },
      "mark": {
        "align": "left",
        "baseline": "middle",
        "dx": 24,
        "fontWeight": "bold",
        "tooltip": "test",
        "type": "text"
      },
      "transform": [
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentageCalc",
              "field": "score_calc",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "groupby": ["agent"],
          "joinaggregate": [
            {
              "as": "ScorePercentage",
              "field": "score_percentage",
              "op": "average"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "params": [
    {
      "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["Top", "Bottom"]},
      "name": "sortChoice"
    },
    {
      "expr": "sortChoice==='Bottom' ? 'ascending':'descending'",
      "name": "sortOrder"
    }
  ],
  "title": "Top Ten Scores",
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"as": "rank", "op": "rank"}]},
    {"filter": "datum.rank <= 10"}
  ],
  "width": 200
}
```